# where to get some map images for deepzoom test data?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, deepzoom

I am developing Silverlight 3.0 deep zoom + C# + .Net 3.5 + VSTS 2008. I need some png or jpg small images to compose to a big map image, or using a big png or jpg map image to test deep zoom effect? Any free ones?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried google? There are tons of large photos out there. Check this site out:http://freelargephotos.com/

Most cameras take 5 to 8 mega pixel images. Borrow a camera if you don't have one.

Comment: Thanks Charles, question answered.